# Metamask doesn't allow me to approve transactions

Tags: metamask, testing

Metamask does'nt allow me to click on confirm when I wan't to approve a transaction.
(i.e. the Confirm button is disabled and stays disabled whatever I do)

[image]

Because "Confirm" is disabled I can't do anything except 'Reject'

```
Store.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) {code: 4001, message: "MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature.", stack: "Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature."}
```

Furtermore Metamask suggests a different account by saying: "Is this the correct account?  It's different from the currently selected account in your wallet" Yes, it is actually different and for a good reason. Both accounts have sufficient funds anyways.

What can I do against it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue - I had sufficient balance in the token that I was sending but not enough ETH for the gas fee.

Comment: The redaction is a little confusing but your answer is right you need some ETH to pay the transaction fee to enable the button.